# simple_format_text equivalent in Twig

Tags: symfony1, twig

[simple_format_text](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/TextHelper#method_simple_format_text) is Symfony 1 helper function.

Is there a Twig equivalent to this function?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the format (or replace) filters - but would require a little tweaking

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/format.html